# How do I get the last part of an ip address string in PHP

Tags: php

If I have an IP such as:

```
195.123.321.456
```

How do I get just the `456` as a variable?

Comment: If you're working with real valid IP's `ip2long($ip)&0xFF` gives you the last octet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $ip = "195.123.321.456";
    $split = explode(".", $ip);
    echo $split[3];

?>
```

Output:

```
456
```

Comment: @Raptor oh your right! But i think he doesn't need regex. Think he only needs a solution for his problem

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\d+(?![^.]*\.)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/22

```
$re = "/\\b\\d+(?![^.]*\\.)/";
$str = "195.123.321.456";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @Jacques it cannot give `1`.See demo

Answer (score 1):

If you store it inside a Var like

```
$var = "195.123.321.456";
```

you can use the preposed php command on string to find the last occurence.

```
$number = substr(strrchr($var , "."), 1);
```

You will have now 456 on $number var

Documentation on strrchr -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Answer (score 1):

You can find this the following way:

```
$ipaddress = '195.123.321.456';

$endValue = end( explode(".", $ipaddress ) );

echo $endValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

U could use also this:

```
$ip = '195.123.321.456';
$last = substr($ip, strrpos($ip, '.') + 1);
```